# According to the doppler effect , if my source is faster than sound , will I hear the sound backwards?

Tags: doppler-effect

In a hypothetical situation,say I have a sound box with a very large volume and let's say it is placed pretty far away from me. If it travels towards me at a speed higher than that of sound in the same medium, air for instance, then will I hear the song playing backwards? 
according to the equation  f' = [v+vo/v+vs]f
where all symbols have their usual meaning , I get a negative f` for vs>v . What does a negative frequency indicate?
I understand a similar question has been asked however the answers didn't satisfy me.
I still believe that before the first pulse reaches the observer , the second pulse is created and so on until the observer hears the 'n'th pulse and then the pulses preceding it.

Comment: Completely unintentional and born of an original idea.

Comment: Hi Keith. It wasn't meant as a criticism. It's just that when a duplicate question exists the answers to that question probably already provide an answer to yours and we try to keep the duplication down to make the site easier to search.

Comment: Hi John, I didn't mean to sound standoffish ,however I went through the answer and found it didn't satisfy me and the answers strayed away from those I was hoping for. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You will hear a sonic boom from a shock wave after the object has passed by you, not before, but the sound will not be "backwards"...

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a simpler case: instead of a song, the fighter pilot emits two pulses separated by some time.  After the first pulse is emitted, he will indeed outrun it - he is after all going faster than the sound speed.  He will then emit a second pulse in front of the first (and outrun that as well).

As a distant observer, *you will indeed then hear the second pulse first*, and in that sense there is an inversion of the time sequence of signals.

Of course we are ignoring practical considerations, but surely this can be observed: a toy boat moving faster than the wave speed in water, with an agitator hanging off to the side some distance so as not to interfere greatly with the wake that it creates.

Comment: What will the pulses have to counter in a practical situation? What assumptions do I make for an ideal situation?

Comment: there is a large, disruptive pressure gradient (shockwave) for supersonic sources.  You can see this as the wake of a boat.  Imagine trying to discern some small ripple pattern traveling through that cresting mess!